# display ViewPager (swipe tab) below Relative layout (not attached to ActionBar )android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I have layout which has some views (`EditText` and `Textview` inside `RelativeLayout` ) and below I need to display ViewPager ( swipe tab ), but android supports ViewPager attached to ActionBar , which is not required in my case.

Current Result :  ActionBar  -->  ViewPager

Expected Result :  ActionBar  --> RelativeLayout --> ViewPager

If needed code I can post ..

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_top_news"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/top_news"
            layout="@layout/top_news"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/container_top_news">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

top_news.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

     <View
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"              
                android:background="@color/border" 
                android:layout_margin="0dip"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_rel_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/title_background"
        >

         <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_photo"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"               
                android:background="@drawable/ic_getimage"                            
                android:padding="10dip" />

         <View
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_photo"
                android:background="@color/border" 
                android:layout_margin="0dip"/>


          <com.rb.lined.edittext.LinedEditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_story"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
                android:background="@null"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
                android:padding="10dip" 
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:imeOptions="actionNone"

                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:gravity="top|left"              
                app:typeface="roboto_condensed"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view2"
               android:minLines="10"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

     <View
                android:id="@+id/view3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"              
                android:background="@color/border" 
                android:layout_margin="0dip"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You currently have:
RelativeLayout
    - top_news
    - ViewPager
As you are not setting any relitive layout options on the children they will both be rendered at the top-left (or in fact the top-start) of the outer layout (i.e. the screen).

If you changed the RelativeLayout to a LinerLayout with vertical orientation then you would get the ViewPager under the top_news.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_top_news"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/top_news"
            layout="@layout/top_news"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container_top_news">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: top_news.xml appears inside the viewpager ... see my code update and result screenshot

Comment: No. In fact, the top_news.xml is under the tabHost and above the viewPager, because viewpager is different component of tabHost in you case. And where is the tabHost code? It's missing. Please, can you add an image or something that explain what you want to do? So I'll help you better :)